Jupyter Notebook debugger: Avoid modifying jupyter environment variables after debugging session ends
I am using jupyter in VSC locally, and I noticed that when we debug a cell, once it finishes and the debugger shuts down all the variable's values got updated in the jupyter's notebook's environment, like if we would have normally ran the cell without the debugger. Is there a way to avoid that a debugging session on a cell modifies the notebook's variables once the debugger shuts down? Like if the debugger could use it's own environment and the action of running code in debug mode doesn't updates the notebook's variables?
The reason why that would be helpful is in cases where we have to debug multiple times the same cell, but each debugging session needs the variables/datesets/objects to have starting values. So if we do the first round of debugging on said cell and variables got manipulated, then trying the second round of debugging would require us to restore the variables back to original values.
However, if the first round of debugging did not ended up overwritten those variables, we could start up the debugger again immediately without having to check if variables have correct starting values for debugging that cell.
That could be a significant difference if we assume "restoring the original values of the variables" is a very lengthy and consuming process. Like if we were talking of large datasets
To put it in a scenario:

Cell #1 has code that loads variables, the code takes 40 mins to run and creates datasets. Once this cell finishes running, the variables/objects/datasets created are  visible in the notebook's jupyter variables view

Cell #2 has code that will modify the values of the variables/datasets/objects produced by cell #1 , and we are not sure if the code here is correct and it's a complex code that will require several rounds of debugging. However, on each round we need to make sure the input datasets/variables/objects to this cell are what cell#1 generates.


If cell#1 is executed and then we enter to debug cell #2, then the debugger at the very first line of code in cell#2 (assuming we put a breakpoint there) will have the variables loaded from cell#1, because when debugging a cell it first "adopts" the current jupyter notebook's environment, which at that point of time is what cell#1 gave as output
Eventually, when we run line per line (or blocks) of cell#2 in our first debugging session , each line/block modifies the variables/datasets, and we can see the modified variables/datasets in the VSC debugger view (as expected).
However, when we finish debugging cell#2 and the debugger shuts down. Then at that point of time when we look at our jupyter variables we see that they got modified as well. Like if we would have ran cell #2 normally without the debugger. So now we need to restore them back by rerunning cell#1 (40 mins process)
Is there a way that while debugging a cell in jupyter and when the debugging session ends the variables in the jupyter's notebook environment are not modified as result of debugging cell#2 ?
Are there any configs/extensions/actions to do this?
I know the most straightforward approach is to create a new cell (lets call it cell#1.5) before cell#2 that cloned the variables so it saves the original ones as backup, so that we can then manually restore them after debugging for the first time in cell#2. But this requires a manual intervention each time we want to debug again. What I am looking for is for a way for either VSC or jupyter to just not modify the notebook's variables during the debugging of a cell to avoid either rerunning code that generates them or having to manually interfere to restore backed-up values/datesets
